# check video file size before playing on iphone

Tags: iphone

I am working on an iphone app that downloads a video from a web server and then plays this video.
my problem is that sometimes the server replies to me with an empty file not a valid video.
how can i check that this is a valid video file before playing?

```
    player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didFinishPlaying:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];
    player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
    [player play];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check file size with help of NSFileManager:

```
NSFileManager* manager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* attributes = [manager attributesOfItemAtPath:[url path] error:&error];
int size = [attributes fileSize];
```

Comment: How did you implement playing video file from webserver.I need to implement it